# How to define new header files with preprocessing directive #define?

Tags: c, linux

I've got some errors when trying to run a script

```
 in file included from main.c:1:0:
 hello.h:1:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #define__HELLO_H
 #define__HELLO_H
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 hello.h:5:2: error: #endif without #if 
 #endif 
 ^~~~~~~
 in file included from hello.c:2:0:
 hello.h:1:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #define__HELLO_H
 #define__HELLO_H
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 hello.h:5:2: error: #endif without #if 
 #endif 
 ^~~~~~~
```

here is my script

```
$ gcc main.c hello.c -o hello 
$ ./hello
```

and here's the 3 file:

file hello.h:

```
 #define __HELLO_H 

 void    hello(); 

 #endif
```

file hello.c:

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include "hello.h" 

 void hello() 
 {      printf("Hello, I am tod,\n");         printf("Welcome to IT007!\n"); 
 }
```

file main.c

```
 #include "hello.h" 

 int main() 
 { 
        hello();    return 0; 
 }
```

I'm a beginner, your help would mean a lot to me, thank you

Comment: You have two identical lines `#define __HELLO_H` in `hello.h`. I suggest using `#pragma once` instead of define guard.

Comment: my bad, it's typing error, the problem now become invalid preprocessing directive #define__HELLO_H

Comment: [Edit] the post to show the latest, full code that you've tried with no typos; and to quote all errors received in full.

Comment: Include a space between `#define` and its operand. Also, to implement include guards properly, you need a corresponding `#ifndef` before the `#define`.

Comment: thank you underscore_d, my bug is fixed, please write down your answer so I can accept it in order to increase your reputation score

Comment: Also, preprocessor macro names that start with one or two underscores are reserved.

Comment: @vannguyenThai Great! I have done so. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must fix your usage of the preprocessor as follows:

- Include a space between `#define` and its operand.
- To implement include guards properly, you need a corresponding `#ifndef` before the `#define`.
- As wildplasser said, you can't use macro names beginning with underscore(s), so remove them, or replace them with some other prefix of your own.

```cpp
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H 

void    hello(); 

#endif // HELLO_H
```